# proper way of calling a function from a different file in PHP

Tags: php

let's say I have a function as so

```
function something($variable){

   $variable = sanitize($variable);
   $variable1 = sanitize($Variable1);

 ......
}
```

When I call this function from a different file and pass 2 variables to it, would this be acceptable?  Let's say I call in this fashion...

```
something($_GET['variable1'], $_POST['variable']);
```

Thank you!

Comment: yes, but I am not get any output.  I get a blank page, that is why I am thinking this is my problem and thus I need to only pass one variable, but if I do that changes my code :(, so I figured to ask before I go that route.  Thanks

Comment: How can you pass two variables when you only have one argument in your function definition?

Comment: Hi Elendil,  based on the answer(s) below it appears that PHP does not require or limits the function's number of parameters passed to it as long as the a path "include" is placed at the very top of the file where you are calling the function from.  which in my case, I do have include('/path/to/functions.php'); at the top of my file.  I hope this helps.  cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as that file is included.

So say `functions.php` has your `something()` function.  You would need to do:

```
include('/path/to/functions.php');
something($_GET['variable1'], $_POST['variable']);
```

Comment: and what this answer?

Comment: Mike, thank you for your answer. I do have it included you have eliminated my doubt about whether this is my problem.  You have answered my question.  Thanks again!

Comment: I have to wait 8 mins to accept your answer :)  and I can't up vote bc I don't have more than 15 reputations :(

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your files are tied together.

If you are using classes and organizing by that, you could declare this static and call it like:

```
yourClassName::something(variable1, variable2);
```

If you are just using includes to link the files, you should be able to do just as you described.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could do that, but you *need* to include the file beforehand (using `require`, `require_once`, `include` or `include_once`). Unlike other languages PHP won't complain that all the params haven't been described beforehand.

This would fail, though, as this specifies that it MUST receive 3 variables:

```
function something($var1, $var2, $var3) {
}
```

If you magically want to get all the parameters posted to a function, you can use [`func_get_args`](http://www.php.net/func_get_args) as so:

```
function something() {
    $arguments = array();

    foreach (func_get_args() as $argument) {
        $arguments[] = sanitize($argument);
    }

    print_r($arguments);
}
```

Here `$arguments[0]` is a sanitized version of `$variable`, and `$arguments[1]` is a sanitized version of `$variable1`.